# Applied material is half black

Tags: materials

[image]

When i linked a material, half of the body is black even though its one object, this material worked on other objects.
Also the head doesn't link with the material.

Comment: Can you post the blend file?

Comment: That screenshot cuts off any potentially useful information, like the Material Properties so we can see how many Material Slots it has, or the Outliner so we could see if there are any other objects that might be obscuring.  But for this it might be best if you included a link to a truncated version of the blend file that has the problem, and with any needed image textures packed. The Blender StackExchange has its own service to share blend files: blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: @KickAir8p ah i see now, there was extra materials on top

Comment: Make sure you delete extra materials.

Comment: what do you mean by extra material? maybe you had onverlapping faces?

Comment: @moonboots i think so, i dont know much about materials

Comment: maybe share your file so that we can check: https://pasteall.org/blend/